# What are the 0x3F 0xB3 bytes for in /dev/fsevents?

Tags: ios, macos, jailbreak, darwin, fsevents

I am experimenting with the [filemon source code](http://www.newosxbook.com/src.jl?tree=listings&file=3-filemon.c). I'm debugging why it crashes on iOS 7. I do not have much experience in fsevents but I noticed that in the bytestream it could read off of from /dev/fsevents it follows this pattern:

(fileop info) (args) 0x3F 0xB3 (fileop info) (args)

Where an arg in (args) follow this format:

(arg id) (arg len) (arg value)

What is 0x3F 0xB3 for? I guess it means 0xBEEF? Is it correct to assume it is a sentinel to separate different file operation info in /dev/fsevents?

Comment: You might consider adding `os x` or `darwin` tags to your question.  You might get an OS X expert who knows.  I'm not sure many iOS (only) experts would have much experience with this, since reading `/dev/fsevents` would be prohibited for sandboxed apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this [header file](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1456.1.26/bsd/sys/fsevents.h):

```
#define FSE_ARG_DONE     0xb33f   // no more arguments
```

So, yes, it's used as a sentinel.

Comment: Thank you! I think I need this header file, too.

Comment: @radj That might not be the latest version, so look around a bit :)